# OS X Monterey PHP 8.1 unable to find oci8.so

Tags: php, oci8, php-8.1, instantclient

I downloaded and installed Oracle InstantClient from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/macos-intel-x86-downloads.html, and installed it via the Instructions for OS X Monterey.

I then ran `arch -arm64e pecl install oci8-3.2.1` for the proper version of `oci8` to use with php 8.1 & Silicon, it reports that it has installed the `oci8` extension and adds the `so` file.

However, when I run `php -a`, the first thing that pops up is that it can't find the `oci8.so`:

```
tried: /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20210902/oci8.so
(dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20210902/oci8.so, 0x0009): 
symbol not found in flat namespace (_OCIAttrGet))
```

The `oci8.so` file exists at that location - I've tried reinstalling both php 8.1 and the oci extension, but still get the same error. Thx for any help!

Comment: Since Oracle Instant Client is only for Intel, shouldn't you be using an Intel PHP and pecl install so that Rosetta works?

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherJones I'll give it another go - this is all done within a Terminal running under Rosetta.

Comment: Thx @ChristopherJones - the issue was that the version of PHP was not compiled for Intel I'll set up an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorted it out. For future reference: all pieces of the puzzle (Oracle, brew, php, oci8) need to be specifically set for Intel:

Download the Oracle InstantClient dmg(s) for OS X (Intel) and install per the documentation on the Oracle download page, then:

1. Copy Terminal App, option-I and set as 'Open with Rosetta'
2. In a Rosetta Terminal, install Homebrew: `arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"`
3. Install php@8.1: `arch -x86_64 /usr/local/Homebrew/bin/brew [re]install php@8.1`
4. Add the x86_64 php@8.1 to your shell `$PATH`
5. Install x86_64 `oci8`: `arch -x86_64 pecl install oci8-3.2.1`
6. Add `instantclient,[/full/path/to/installed/instantclient/directory]` when prompted
7. Add `extension=oci8.so` to `php.ini` if not automatically added after the `PECL` install, and `extension_dir` as needed
8. `php -a` will return `function_exists('oci_connect')` as `true`

Note that the above installs the InstantClient for the cli only - you'll need additional configuration if you want to run a server using the Intel PHP; that info is in the output from the php install step.